# how to summarize one variable through group_by on another variable, so the output variable is connected to grouped variable

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I'm trying to summarize the counts of one variable through grouping one variable, so that the total_count is connected to each row of the grouped variable.

I want to be able to add the "emp" column by grouping fam_id, so that total_employed reflects the numbers of employed in family for all within the same fam_id

acs_5years

```
fam_id  emp  ins  age
33      1    1    45
33      0    1    23
44      1    1    19
44      1    0    26
44      1    0    54
44      1    0    50
77      1    1    33
77      1    1    38
77      1    1    44
88      1    0    65
88      0    0    90
```

should look like:

```
fam_id  emp  ins  age  total_employed
33      1    1    45     1
33      0    1    23     1
44      1    1    19     4
44      1    0    26     4
44      1    0    54     4
44      1    0    50     4
77      1    1    33     3
77      1    1    38     3
77      1    1    44     3
88      1    0    65     1
88      0    0    90     1
```

I've tried the following code:

```
sample_grouping <- acs_5years %>% group_by(fam_id) %>%
  summarize(total_count=n(),.groups = 'drop') %>%
  as.data.frame()

sample_grouping
```

#######

```
sample_2 <- acs_5years %>% group_by(fam_id) %>%
  summarize(total_count=(emp))

sample_2
```

I'm not sure I'm getting correct results.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`emp` of `fam_id` `44` is different and your code is different with your data, but you may try

```
df %>%
  group_by(fam_id) %>%
  mutate(total_employed = sum(emp))

   fam_id   emp   ins   age total_employed
    <int> <int> <int> <int>          <int>
 1     33     1     1    45              1
 2     33     0     1    23              1
 3     44     1     1    19              3
 4     44     1     0    26              3
 5     44     1     0    54              3
 6     44     0     0    50              3
 7     77     1     1    33              3
 8     77     1     1    38              3
 9     77     1     1    44              3
10     88     1     0    65              1
11     88     0     0    90              1
```